# RHEL 8.6 - pgrep hangs

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an issue with pgrep which hangs and doesn't return anything.

The problem is that I'm not even sure where to start debugging.
Could anyone suggest anything?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]?

Comment: Are you setting `LD_PRELOAD` before calling pgrep?

Comment: No. LD_PRELOAD is empty